# How to upgrade packages from where they are installed from?

Tags: debian, backports, dist-upgrade

I run `apt-get upgrade`, which says there is nothing to upgrade to:

```
# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                                        
Hit:4 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease                                                                              
Get:5 http://nginx.org/packages/debian buster InRelease [3,589 B]                                                                          
Hit:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                                                                                
Hit:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                                                       
Hit:10 https://www.deb-multimedia.org buster InRelease                                                                          
Hit:9 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease    
Fetched 9,177 B in 2s (5,558 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However, I installed my kernel from `buster-backports` by:

```
# apt-get install -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64
```

Current version is `5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64`:

```
# uname -a
Linux erik3 5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.6-1~bpo10+1 (2020-11-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

...and it has an update:

```
root@erik3:~# apt-cache policy linux-image-amd64
linux-image-amd64:
  Installed: 4.19+105+deb10u8
  Candidate: 4.19+105+deb10u8
  Version table:
     5.9.15-1~bpo10+1 100
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.19+105+deb10u8 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.19+105+deb10u7 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

However, `apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` ignores any updates from where the package actually belongs to.

## Question

How can I tell `apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade the packages from backports if I installed those packages from backports?

Answer (score 3):

> However, I installed my kernel from `buster-backports`, so it has an update:

Not exactly. You added the backports repository to your sources, but you didn't install the package.

Packages from backports are not automatically installed (apt setting `NotAutomatic: yes`), but upgraded once they are installed (`ButAutomaticUpgrades: yes`, priority 100).

Version `4.19+105+deb10u8` is installed (and also the install candidate), `5.9.15-1~bpo10+1` has a lower priority of 100 and needs to be installed manually with

```
apt -t buster-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

Upgrades will then install newer versions of the package from backports automatically (unless there are other
sources with a higer priority and newer versions).

Comment: I edited my question to make it more explicit. Yes, I installed `linux-image-64` from backports manually (Otherwise you wouldn't see the backports version in the `uname -a` output). `apt-get upgrade` still refuses to look backports for that package.

Comment: Well, your own `apt-cache policy` output says you didn’t. That suggests you installed a specific kernel from backports (`linux-image-5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64`), instead of the meta-package. Does that ring any bells? Or perhaps you upgraded the meta-package then inadvertently downgraded it.