# How to list installed packages manually from backports?

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I need to get a list of manually installed packages from backports, in order to ["complete"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629379/how-to-upgrade-packages-from-where-they-are-installed-from) the `apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` sequence. Following command lists the packages that are manually installed from backports:

```
$ # based on: https://serverfault.com/a/109680/261445
$ aptitude search "?narrow(~i, ~Abackports) ?not(?automatic)" | sed 's/ - .*//'
i  btrfs-progs
i  checkinstall
i  linux-headers-5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
i  linux-image-5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
i  spl-dkms
i  zfs-dkms
i  zfsutils-linux
```

However, I never gave a command like:

```
apt-get install -t buster-backports linux-image-5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
```

so the output is not accurate. I installed the kernel by `apt-get install -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64` command so I expect to get `linux-image-amd64` and not `linux-image-5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64`.

How can I get the list of what I really manually installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aptitude` command *is* accurate: it lists all packages currently installed, from backports, and not marked as automatically installed.

The fact that this doesn’t output what you expect it to is another issue, and one we can’t solve for you. Something caused your `linux-image-amd64` meta-package to be reverted to the Debian 10 version. Presumably in a related event, no doubt helped by the protection given to the currently-active kernel and to meta-packages, the actual kernel image and headers packages from backports lost their “automatic” marker.

The packaging system only knows what its current state is, not how it got there.

To solve your underlying problem, you should run

```
sudo apt -t buster-backports install linux-{image,headers}-amd64
```

which will upgrade the meta-packages to their backported versions and install the corresponding real packages.

After that, `apt upgrade` will upgrade any out-dated backport versions *without* requiring you to manually figure out what packages came from backports.

If you mark the old kernel packages as automatically installed, your system will be in the state you want it to be in and the `aptitude` command will give the output you expect:

```
sudo apt-mark auto linux-{headers,image}-5.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
```

If you really want to figure out what happened, the logs in `/var/log/apt` should tell you, but `apt` and co. can’t use that information themselves.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused: Will the original `aptitude` commad give the "correct" output if I re-install image/header with `apt -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64` command? Or you are suggesting that I should resolve this particular issue manually every time?

Comment: If you adjust the system state so that it matches what you expect it to be, then yes, the original `aptitude` command will give the output you expect. Its output is always correct; it’s just that the state it reflects isn’t what you think it should be. See the update.

Comment: Note that even after marking the packages as `auto`, `linux-image-amd64` didn't show up within the above list. I needed to "install" it (again?) manually (I'm sure I did before, I don't know how those conflicts occurred)

Comment: Yes, I said in my answer that you’d have to re-install that package.